# Django cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf'

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой в одном из проектов.

> cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf'

Встречал кто? Есть лекарство?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас `Visual studio`, то переустановите окружение.
Ошибка явно намекает на то, что `Django` нет.
В `Visual Studio` показывало, что окружение `Python 3.7`, создал новое и все заработало.
GL HF.